# Add expand/collapse button in large table

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I have HTML like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <style>
         th {
         border: 1px solid black;
         border-bottom: 3px solid black;
         text-align: center;
         color: #121111;
         background-color: #59ebbd;
         position: sticky;
         top: 0;
         }
         
         td {
         border: 1px solid grey;
         padding: 2px;
         }

         table {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         table-layout: fixed;
         white-space: nowrap;
         }
 
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <table border="0" class="df data">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>count</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>3</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>3</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>3</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>3 </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>3</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>60</td>
                  <td>3</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Looking for easiest solution to avoid scrolling large tables in html - I want to display first n-th rows from table (collapsed) and have access to rest of it (expanded).

so it can be expand/collapse button after 5th row like:

[image]

I was looking over web for hint how to do it, but I only found a solution to collapse/expand each row in table - that is not what Im looking for. I look for solution to collapse/expand whole table at once, when table exceed n-th number of rows.

I've done something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/nfLhzxb7/

but still don't know how to make 5-7 rows disapearing.

Answer (score 0):

Like this one? https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-collapsible-expandable-row-table-26382307 please add some more code. usually this is done in JavaScript

Comment: it can be like this, but need only one button for one table.